# Posting on another user's wall using Feed Dialogue and Javascript API

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to allow the current user to post to another user's wall using the feed dialogue and JavaScript API.  I'm using the following code but its prompting the user to post to his own wall and not to the target user's wall:

```
var obj = {method: 'feed', to: targetId, name: name, description: description, link: link, caption: caption, picture: pictureLink, ref: ref};
FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps targetId does not properly cast to a string, or perhaps it does not contain a valid id.

You could test it, by providing a string literal with a valid id, in stead of a variable.